# I am trying to write a script that will extract hourly values from a web page table into excel

Tags: vba, excel

The table is in 15 minute intervals but I only need the values that are every Hour.  Is there a way to tell the vba to only read the values that are timestamped to HH:00:00?

```
Sub GetWaterLevels()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Clears previously loaded data
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4:D85").ClearContents

    URL = "http://waterdata.quinteconservation.ca/KiWIS/KiWIS?service=kisters&type=queryServices&request=getTimeseriesValues&datasource=0&format=html&ts_id=3641042&metadata=true&md_returnfields=station_name,ts_name,ts_unitname&&period=PT10H&width=600&height=400"

    'Downloads the table into excel
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
        Destination:=Range("C4"))

    With qt
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .Name = "WaterLevels"
        .FieldNames = True
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: http://waterdata.quinteconservation.ca/KiWIS/ has very good documentation. Did you explore changing the URL query string to try and get a different input?

Answer (score 0):

I learn something new everyday.  The way you get that table is amazingly fast.  My skills are no where near as good as yours, but with the dilemma you have the below is the only answer I can come up with.  I don't know if you can select certain rows with your method or not on the import side.  I looked at webtables property but don't know enough about it.  What I would do is cull the table once it is on my sheet with the following code.  When I use your code to import the table it puts the active data starting on row 10.  You might have to adjust that to suit your needs.

```
Sub sortTable()
Dim lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long, myArray1, myArray2, myCounter As Long, i As Long
'   When I ran your getWaterLevels script it put the data starting on row 10
    firstRow = 10
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row

myCounter = 1
ReDim myArray1(1 To 1)
ReDim myArray2(1 To 1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = firstRow To lastRow
        If Range("C" & i).Value <> "" And InStr(1, Range("C" & i).Value, ":00:00.") > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To myCounter)
            ReDim Preserve myArray2(1 To myCounter)
            myArray1(myCounter) = Range("C" & i)
            myArray2(myCounter) = Range("D" & i)
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
        End If
    Next i



    Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Range("C10:D" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select

    myCounter = 10

    For i = LBound(myArray1) To UBound(myArray1)
        Range("C" & myCounter).Value = myArray1(i)
        Range("D" & myCounter).Value = myArray2(i)
        myCounter = myCounter + 1
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```